# Understanding polymorphism in general (c# example)

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, abstract-class

I am currently in the middle of self-teaching some basic concepts of C# and I am experimenting with abstract classes and polymorphism. I thought I got the basic concept but it turned out that the concept doesn't work like I understood it :). However - I hope I get some answers which clear the dust a little bit :).

The whole task I am trying to achieve is to extend an abstract base class and use the extension with an object of the base class. Like here:

I have an abstract class which implements an abstract property like:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
   public abstract MyProperty mP{get;}
}
```

where the property is

```
public abstract class MyProperty 
{
   public abstract string PropertyName{get;}
}
```

Now I am deriving the MyProperty class for an actual implementation like

```
public class DerivedProperty : MyProperty
{
  public override string PropertyName
  {
    get
    {
      return this._name;
    }
  }

  private _name = "Property1";

 /* some other implementation follows here...... */
}
```

As I've understood polymorphism and inheritance it should now be possible to instantiate a derived class from BaseClass and override the property MyProperty with an object of DerivedProperty like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override DerivedProperty mP
  {
    get
    {
      return dP;
    }
  }

  private DerivedProperty dP = new DerivedProperty();

  /* more implementation follows here...... */
}
```

Because DerivedProperty is an object of MyProperty and DerivedProperty at the same time it is possible to use it where either MyProperty or DerivedProperty is referenced. At least that's what I thought but it seems that this is wrong. 
Now I am wondering - why is polymorphism so useful when something like above is not possible? Because even when I try something like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override MyProperty mP
  {
    get
    {
      return dP as DerivedProperty;
    }
  }

  private DerivedProperty dP = new DerivedProperty();

  /* more implementation follows here...... */
}
```

I still get only my base object MyProperty and not my extended object DerivedProperty which I want to get.
I know why I get those results - I just don't seem logical to me :). Is it really like polymorphism is supposed to work or is my implementation just crap and I have to do it in a different way to get my extended property?

Appreciate your help here!

Comment: Just to let you know. `m_`, `_` are typically prefixes reserved for private fields (for example `m_darkCage` or `_darkCage`). Public properties are usually named using upper case first letter (for example `BrightRoom`). `Property` suffix is rather reserved for dependency properties. In real life example you will usually not use `Class` string inside class name (in this example maybe it is not so bad). `/* */` comments are used typically to comment block of code. Text comments usually are created by `//`. You will find that most of the projects (most of the time) stick to those rules.

Comment: There are exceptions to those rules (for example control names created by designer sometimes are not prefixed `m_` or `_` but still developers accept those). It is good to learn c# naming conventions because they are widely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the same type for overrided property. You can use it later in your abstract BaseClass.  Parameters as well as return value of member have to be the same when overriding. It is usually not a problem.

I've prepared following examples that my code look similar to yours.

In some scenarios I've seen that there is added second property with more specific type and different (more specific) name:

```
public abstract class BaseCar
{
    public abstract BaseDriver Driver { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseDriver
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AgressiveDriver : BaseDriver
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FastCar : BaseCar
{
    private AgressiveDriver _agressiveDriver = new AgressiveDriver();

    public override BaseDriver Driver { get { return _agressiveDriver; } }
    public AgressiveDriver AgressiveDriver { get { return _agressiveDriver; } }
}
```

Second approach is to use generics:

```
public abstract class BaseCar<TDriver> 
    where TDriver : BaseDriver
{
    public abstract TDriver Driver { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseDriver
{
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AgressiveDriver : BaseDriver
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FastCar : BaseCar<AgressiveDriver>
{
    private AgressiveDriver _agressiveDriver = new AgressiveDriver();

    public override AgressiveDriver Driver { get { return _agressiveDriver; } }
}
```

but I think first approach is better because there is no problem with creating/using BaseCar objects (for example to create BaseCar<> variable you have to specify type parameter). Also it makes sense to create more specific name for more specific property.

Comment: Thanks - that helped me to understand what I am doing wrong or what I have to do better in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an extra bit of complexity you don't need.  You have an abstract class inside an abstract class.  If you are just learning/relearning this you have skipped a couple easy steps for understanding.  Here's a simpler example to start with.

```
public abstract class Shape
{

   public abstract double GetArea();
   public abstract double Circumference();
}


public class Square: Shape
{
    public double width {get; set;}

    public override double GetArea()
    {
        return width * width;
    }

    public override Circumference()
    {
        return width * 4;
    }
}
```

You can now instantiate a Square or create a Circle Class and be able to use either where you use Shape.